# VS Code cannot find module in my Typescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd, visual-studio-code

My project is a [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) project with a browser part and a server part. Because of that, I need to have two separate `tsconfig.json` in order to build the browser library and the server process using node. I am using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

#### The project

Here is the folder structure:

```
myproject
 |
 +-src
 |  |
 |  +-server
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-server.ts
 |  |  +-<several-ts-files>
 |  |  +-tsconfig.ts
 |  +-main.ts
 |  +-<several-ts-files>
 |  +-disposable.ts
 |  +-tsconfig.ts
 +-out
```

When building the server, I will go: `tsc --project src\server`, when building the client, I will go: `tsc --project src`.

#### The problem

In one of my files: `src\main.ts`, I have the following:

```
import disposable = require('./disposable.ts');

export module Browser {
  export class MyClass implements disposable.Disposable {
    // Stuff
  }
}
```

Since the browser side part uses AMD, I am specifying it in `src/tsconfig.json`: `"module": "amd"`!
Visual Studio Code marks `'./disposable.ts'` inside the `require` with a red line with error:

> Cannot find module './disposable.ts'

#### Questions

1. Is this two `tsconfig.json` approach wrong?
2. Why can't Code find my modules?

#### Can it be...

I remember once somebody told me that Code needs a `tsconfig.json` file to understand how the developer wants to build the code. However when we have two and they are not in the root? Do all editors behave like that?

Comment: Hi Andry - I can't see the disposable.ts file listed in your project structure. Can you add it in so we can see it in your tree view you created?

Comment: Hi Steve, I was implying by the import path that the file is in `src`. But you're right, it is much better to be precise and clear. Edited! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'./disposable.ts'`

Should be `'./disposable'` i.e. drop the `.ts` extension.

Comment: I even watched your video on youtube... Just missed that detail. Thanks man and sorry for the stupid mistake